# How to specify the Typescript type checking directory?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

Currently the directory is like this,

```
src
stories
test
```

tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "rootDirs": ["src", "stories"]
},
"exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "scripts"],
"include": ["src/**/*"]
```

This config has the right build result, which contains all the result from src. But all the type checking is all failed at stories directory.

If I add "stories" directory into "rootDir", the type checking is right, but the build result is not. So how I can config tsconfig.json to enable the type checking at "stories" directory, without affecting the build result, which is not including the "stories".